# $http does not send a request / no network activity

Tags: php, angularjs

At the moment I created a table of database entries. I want the user to be able to refresh the table by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> but not reload the whole page.

I use a routeprovider to load the table into my `index.html`. Then I use this directive to catch the <kbd>F5</kbd> keydown and prevent the default.

```
app.directive('test', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        scope:{
            test: "&",
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
            angular.element($window).on('keydown', function (event){
                if(event.which == 116){
                    scope.test();
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I assigned this directive to the container of my table and used it to call my `table_reload` function in the controller. The controller function calls a method of my `database_factory` to execute my database request.

For the request I use the `$http` object to do my POST request.

```
app.factory("database_factory", function($http){
    var run = function(data, url){
        var request = {
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : url,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': "application/json",
            },
            data    : data
        }
        return $http(request);
    }
    return {
        execute: function(data, url){
            return run(data, url);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that in this constellation the request is not send. There is no network activity and nothing on the console. The code works perfectly well till it reaches the `$http` request. In every other constellation the database connection works perfectly fine.

**EDIT:**

This is how I include the `database_factory` in the controlller:

```
app.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope,$http,database_factory){
```

and this is how I call it:

```
var response=database_factory.execute(transport_data,"json.test.php");
```

Comment: And how does the controller call the `database_factory`?

Comment: Maybe add it to the question and format it? It doesn't look right..

Comment: And that call is done right in the controller function? not in the `scope.test()`-function or anything?

Comment: @Gustav it is in the $scope.reload_page of the contoller but everything workes fine, i have a console.log one line above the request and everything is fine. i even get an object back from the request but $http does not create a POST call. i just get an empty respose promis object.

Comment: In the question you say: "There is no network activity and nothing on the console." Maybe you can elaborate a bit what the problem is...

Comment: @Gustav I changed the factory into a service. Now its working. Thanks for your help. Still have no idea why this happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the database_factory into a database_serive solved the problem.